# Rails 3: How to restrict access to the web interface for adding oauth authorized applications using Doorkeeper gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Rails Application Which uses Device + doorkeeper.I am also using cancan for Role Management.In my application i uses `http://localhost:3000/oauth/applications/new` for registering my application for getting Client and Secret id.
Currently any user can register application through web interface for getting client and secret id ,i need to restrict access so that only admin can register Application.

I saw some code in `doorkeeper.rb` file

```
# If you want to restrict access to the web interface for adding oauth authorized applications, you need to declare the block below.
  # admin_authenticator do
  #   # Put your admin authentication logic here.
  #   # Example implementation:
  #   Admin.find_by_id(session[:admin_id]) || redirect_to(new_admin_session_url)
  # end
```

I tried like below ,but not working...

```
admin_authenticator do
  if(current_user)
    current_user.role? :admin
  else
    redirect_to(new_user_session_url)
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance......

Comment: It seems a bug, post an issue on the github page: https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper

Comment: i have tried like this,and it works........     admin_authenticator do
redirect_to(new_user_session_url) unless (current_user.role? :admin)
end

Comment: Have you tried just returning nil? So, something like this: `admin_authenticator { nil }`. See what that does, if you can still access /oauth/applications then this seems to be a bug

Answer (score 7):

The code I used and works great is

```
admin_authenticator do
  redirect_to new_user_session_url unless current_user && current_user.admin?
end
```

Comment: Maybe a better one is `redirect_to new_user_session_url unless current_user.try(:admin?)` but I haven't tested it

Comment: This one is perfect :)

Comment: Using `redirect_to new_user_session_url unless current_user.try(:admin?)` 
works.

Answer (score 5):

Well, your logic is incorrect. Basically you are letting everyone who is a current_user have access. You really want something like:

```
admin_authenticator do
  if(current_user && current_user.role?(:admin))
    #do nothing
  else
    redirect_to(new_user_session_url)
  end
end
```

You could also do

```
admin_authenticator do
  if(current_user)
    redirect_to(not_authorized_url) unless current_user.role?(:admin)
  else
    redirect_to(new_user_session_url)
  end
end
```

Which would let you send the user to the correct error page